# Can I restore a Redis key when overwrite it by RENAME command

Tags: redis, recovery

I made a horrible mistake by using the command `RENAME key1 key2`. The data in key2 was completely wiped out. Is there anyway to restore the data that was stored in key2?

Comment: NO, you CANNOT. The data related to `key2` has been deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you don't have a `dump`'ed value of `key2`, `key2`'s data is gone. If you have the dumped value, then you can restore it by RESTORE command.

```
RESTORE key2 0 "<dumped value.>"
```

Check out the following links>

- [Dump](https://redis.io/commands/dump)
- [Restore](https://redis.io/commands/restore)